# How to check if a value is present in a list?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I would like to get the list of posts having a specific tag in their front matter (*)

I tried the code below, which iterates over all the tags of the current post pages (the current tag is `t`), then iterates over all the posts (`p`) to check if they have this tag (and just outputs the title, for debugging reasons):

```
{% for t in page.tags %}
    {% for p in site.posts %}
        {% if t in p.tags %}
            {{ p.title }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The line `{% if t in p.tags %}` seems to fail (I come form a Python background so I gave it a try) and I cannot find the `in` operator in liquid. Does it exits?

(*) <sub>I am mentioning what I want to achieve in case there is a more straightforward way to do that but I am still interested in the general question.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following your example it can be done with the [contains](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/basics/operators#contains) tag:

> contains can also check for the presence of a string in an array of
>   strings.
>
> ```
> {% if product.tags contains "outdoor" %}   
> This product is great for
> using outdoors! 
> {% endif %}
> ```

So to get the list of posts having a specific tag in their front matter (in this case the posts with the tag `mytag`):

```
{% assign posts_with_mytag =  site.posts | where_exp:"item",
"item.tags contains 'mytag'" %}

{% for post in posts_with_mytag %}
<a href="{{post.url}}">{{post.title}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following-up on @maracuny's answer, the corrected code from my question for completeness:

```
{% for t in page.tags %}
    {% for p in site.posts %}
        {% if p.tags contains t %}
            {{ p.title }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```